# CSS height transition not working on iphone after first visit to page

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, iphone

I have a site where the css transition for the navigation and footer bar isn't working correctly on the iphone. I'm using SASS compiled into compressed CSS. I've tried to remove `overflow:hidden;` and to use margins instead of height, but none of it is working. I've never had this problem, and I don't know what could be causing this.

The live version of the site is http://connectroot.com

This is also happening on this site: http://pbwebd.com/testing/ewealth

The most recent site is: http://pbwebd.com/testing/artists-theme/

The menu and footer bar works fine when the browser is emulating the iphone, but not on an actual device.

The first time you visit the site, everything works perfectly. If you navigate to another page on the site, the menu or bottom bar do not slide to the correct height. No matter what page you go to, even back to the home page, nothing works correctly. The site is built using WordPress.

Since the same problem happens with the navigation and the footer bar, I will show you just the navigation code.

The SASS:

```
.nav-wrapper {
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  @include transition(height);
  @media #{$bpNAV2}{
    height: 0;
    &.open {
      height: 225px;
    }
  }
}
@mixin transition($type){
-webkit-transition: $type 300ms;
   -moz-transition: $type 300ms;
    -ms-transition: $type 300ms;
     -o-transition: $type 300ms;    
        transition: $type 300ms;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

}

The menu PHP:

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="nav-div">
        <nav>
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary')); ?>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-nav-div">
        <nav>
            <?php $obj = get_queried_object();
            $custom_post_type = $obj->post_type;
            if(is_user_logged_in() && has_nav_menu('subdir')){
                echo '<div id="subdir-nav">';
                wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'subdir'));
                echo '</div>';
            } elseif(has_nav_menu('sub')){
                echo '<div id="sub-nav">';
                wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'sub'));
                echo '</div>';
            } ?>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
$("#toggle").on('click', function(event){
    $(".nav-wrapper").toggleClass('open');
});
```

For this site: http://pbwebd.com/testing/artists-theme/, all the pages work, but the home page only works on the fist visit to the page. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. This is another version of the JS:

```
$('#toggle').on('click touchstart', function(){
    $('nav').toggleClass('show');
    return false;
});
```

If I turn the phone off and on, the menu works again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I include the `touch` event in the javascript, it seems to fix the issue. Here is the updated JS:

```
$("#toggle").on('click touch', function(event){
    $(".nav-wrapper").toggleClass('open');
    return false;
});
```

***This does not fix the issue for all sites, just for some.